# An error occurred. Please try again later. getLoginUrl()

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I've been assign to work in facebook api. But I have this one problem, it gives me this error: ***An error occurred. Please try again later***. By the way I'm using Codeigniter framework.

For now I have this:

```
function sns()
    {
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        if($user) {
            try {
                $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
                echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($data['user_profile'], true)).'</pre>';
            }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
                $data['user'] = NULL;
            }
        }

        if($user) {
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        } else {
            $params = array( 
                    'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
                    'redirect_uri' => site_url('/home/sns')
                );

            $data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        }

        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('home/sns');
    }
```

in my url:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=106015366186236&redirect_uri=%2Fhome%2Fsns&state=dc55eb577e1c2e6ae32dea030bc5c7b7&scope=read_stream%2C+friends_likes

I think my problem is the redirect_uri parameter part. What I want is after logged-in via fb it will redirect back to my sns function/method. Am I doing it right? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be currently down.

Your site URL should be a URI, like http://somedomain.com/sns/ not a path in the system. As this is a HTTP redirect from Facebook in your users's browser